# Searching an arrayList for numbers

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to write a program where I have to store clients number address and id 
I created arrayList for all
one of the options is that the program ask for the id number and gives the information if it doesnt exist display not found

Here's what I have wrote for searching for the client Id

```
public static List<Integer> findClient (List<Integer> idnumbers, Integer searchterm )
    {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer idnum : idnumbers)
        {
            if(idnum.contains(searchterm))
                result.add(idnum);
        }
        return result;

    }
```

I get red lines on the .contains saying "The method contains (Integer) is undefined for the type Integer"

Any help how can I fix that?

Comment: change idnum.contains to result.contains... but you should use a Set so you don't have to do that check

Answer (score 2):

contains is a method on Collection so you can use it on your array list but not on Integer

for your case, you  need to use equals method on Integer. here is the modified method:

```
public static List<Integer> findClient (List<Integer> idnumbers, Integer searchterm )
    {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer idnum : idnumbers)
        {
            if(idnum.equals(searchterm))
                result.add(idnum);
        }
            return result;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List idnumbers
```

Should be changed to

```
List<Integer> idnumbers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(idnumbers.contains(searchterm))
```

Can't call contains on an Integer. It's only one number...

Answer (score 0):

Although you got write answer but a few thing you can change to meet your requirement.

You have to store client number, address and id but in arraylist you are just saving id.

better you should make a class for client like this

```
class Client{
  int id;
  String address;
  String number;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Now store client information in arraylist of type Client like this -

```
ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
```

and then to search a particular client you have to way -

1 - through directly checking id of each client in arraylist like this -

```
for(Client client:clients){
  if(client.getId==idToSearch)
    return client;
}
```

2 - override equals method of your client class in a way that it will check if id of the client is same then they are same. You can use your ide to generate equals method then directly use contains mehtod like this

//Make a constructor with id for client class

```
Client client = new client(idToSearch);
if(clients.contains(client)){
  clients.get(clients.indexOf(client));
}
```

I will prefer 2nd way hope it helps in your code design.

Comment: do you by any chance do tutoring I kind of get what you are saying but I'm having a hard time following along

Comment: Well you can add comment what you tried and what is the difficulty will try my best helping you out

Comment: I got lost on the arrayList part because I made 4 arrayList yet on yours you only made one. Am I suppose to add all the information to that array using client.add(userinput);? or no?

Comment: No you can see arraylist is of type Client so with the input you got you will create an object of client. and then you will directly put the client object in the arraylist something like this. 

Client client = new Client();

client.setId(idInput);
client.setAddress(addressInput);
client.setNumber(numberInput);
clients.add(client);